# Why is $dS=\frac{dQ}{T}$?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, entropy, history

From the sources I've read it I found that it was "found by clausius" but how did he find it? What was the motivation?

I know of the clausius inequality and the fact that summing up the quantity $\frac{dQ}{T}$ over the whole cycle of a heat engine is equal to or less than zero always. However why is that for a reversible process we can write a state function for it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of the Clausius theorem. The background to it is explained in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius_theorem).

We know that in a heat engine that goes through a cycle and returns to its original state, we have

$\oint \frac 1 T dQ \le 0$

with equality only if the cycle is reversible. This tells us that if we move from state $A$ to state $B$ in a reversible way then the quantity

$\int_A^B \frac 1 T dQ$

is always the same, regardless of the actual path taken from $A$ to $B$ (as long as it is reversible). And this in turn tells us that there is a quantity

$S = \int \frac 1 T dQ$

(defined up to an additive constant) which is a function of the state of a system alone (i.e. not dependent of the history of that system) as long as the system only undergoes reversible changes. This quantity is what we call entropy.

Comment: I think you may have use gradient theorem implictly here?

Comment: one more question clausius inequality says that entropy change over a loop is less than 0 but still second law of thermo says that total entropy change should be greater than 0 would this suggest that the surroundings increases entropy?

Comment: "We know that in a heat engine that goes through a cycle and returns to its original state...", I could be wrong but I think the OP wants to know how do we  know that? How did Clausius come to that conclusion?

Comment: yes!! exactly what I was trying to say